how to change to JetBrains Mono on vs code
I can't change vs code settings to JetBrains Mono
I already downloaded the font and made these settings:
{
  "workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.c": "default",
    "*.exe": "default"
  },
  "git.autofetch": true,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "C_Cpp.default.customConfigurationVariables": {},
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
  "settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": [],
  "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
 
  "editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains Mono",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true      
}

and still on consolas
